# How to include managed properties in SharePoint 2013 REST api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest, search-results

I want to include managed properties in the REST api call in SP 2013, but when I try, it doesn't include them. For example

```
http://mydev/_api/search/query?querytext='bob'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&refiners='Group Preference'&selectproperties='Group Preference'
```

and that column is checked `indexable`. But it is not included with the results xml.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the property retrievable? Are you authenticated or is it anonymous?

Comment: Ii looks like you are using People search. Is your custom property in the PeopleIdx?